# base_layer not showing in ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, leaflet, ggmap, stamen-maps

I would like to as kfor any advice how to solve ggmap issue.

lets suppose we have some spatial model and residuals and then we would like to plot it in the map.
When using `ggmap` function I can see baseline background plot and regend for `base_layer - fill`, however it cannot be seen in the plot.

I provide reproduceble example:

```
library(ggmap)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)


#map background
bboxPrague <- c(14.22,49.94,14.71,50.18)
ggMapPrague <- get_map(location = bboxPrague, source = "stamen",maptype = "toner", crop = TRUE, zoom = 12)
ggmap(ggMapPrague)

d = data.frame(
  pred_res = runif(2000, -50, 50),
  lon = runif(2000, 49.94, 50.18),
  lat = runif(2000, 14.22, 14.71)

)
d

#top&bottom coding and discreting pred_res....8
d$res_coded<-replace(d$pred_res,d$pred_res<(-1),8)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=-1,7)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=-0.4,6)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=-0.1,5)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=0,4)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=0.1,3)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=0.4,2)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=1,1)

d %>% head

d$res_coded %>% head

d$res_coded = as.factor(d$res_coded)

ggmap(ggMapPrague, base_layer = ggplot(d, aes(x = lat, y = lon, fill = res_coded)),extent="device",legend = "topleft") + 
  geom_tile(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdYlGn",name="Residual",labels = c("[1;+inf)","[0.4;1)","[0.1;0.4)","[0;0.1)","[-0.1;0)","[-0.4;-0.1)","[-1;-0.4)","(-inf;-1)"))
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but do have a look at `?cut` for converting continuous variables to factors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to set `base_layer = ggplot(aes(...), ...)`, one still needs to specify a geom (geometric object) layer, such as `geom_point(aes(...))`, `geom_rect(aes(...))` or `geom_polygon(aes(...))` appending to the `ggmap(...)`, in order to have data used in base_layer mapped to visual effects.

For example,

```
+ geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = res_coded)) +
```

[image: demo1-orignal-legend]

We can also remove the background grey square in legend keys for a better visual (IMO), by appending with:

```
+ theme(legend.key=element_blank())
```

---

Note: in your example, `lat` and `lon` should be swapped -- we usually have `x = lon, y = lat`. See the fixes in the following demo code.

### Demo

[image: demo-full]

```
library(ggmap)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)


# map background
# bbox = c( left = min(lon), bottom = min(lat), right = max(lon), top = max(lat) )
bboxPrague <- c(14.22,49.94,14.71,50.18) 
ggMapPrague <- get_map(location = bboxPrague, source = "stamen",maptype = "toner", crop = TRUE, zoom = 12)
ggmap(ggMapPrague)

d = data.frame(
  pred_res = runif(2000, -50, 50),
  lat = runif(2000, 49.94, 50.18),
  lon = runif(2000, 14.22, 14.71)

)
d

#top&bottom coding and discreting pred_res....8
d$res_coded<-replace(d$pred_res,d$pred_res<(-1),8)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=-1,7)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=-0.4,6)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=-0.1,5)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=0,4)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=0.1,3)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=0.4,2)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=1,1)

d %>% head

d$res_coded %>% head

d$res_coded = as.factor(d$res_coded)


ggmap(ggMapPrague, 
      base_layer = ggplot(d, aes(x = lon, y = lat)),
      extent="device",
      legend = "topleft") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = res_coded)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(
    palette="RdYlGn",
    name="Residual",
    labels = c("[1;+inf)","[0.4;1)","[0.1;0.4)",
               "[0;0.1)","[-0.1;0)","[-0.4;-0.1)",
               "[-1;-0.4)","(-inf;-1)")) +
  theme(legend.key=element_blank())
```

---

### Issue with `geom_tile`

`geom_tile` draws rectangles specified by `(center_x, center_y, width, height)`, when `width` and `height` are unspecified, they will be calculated as the minimum gap between two adjacent points, that is, `width = min(abs(diff(df$x)))` and `height = min(abs(diff(df$y)))`. In your case, the `width = min(abs(diff(d$lon))) ~ 0.0001525275` and `height = min(abs(diff(d$lat))) ~ 3.292719e-05` (due to `runif`, actual value may vary a bit).

This kind of automation will cause problem given the example or GPS coordinates represents "raw points" rather than "center of each region", because the gap between two adjacent "raw points" can be too narrow to worth a pixel to draw. In this case, we will have to manually specify the `width` and `height` and bear in mind that the tiles will overlap.

Consider your example, with:

```
+ geom_tile(aes(fill=res_coded, height = 3E-3, width=3E-3))

# note that when `height` and `width` is small enough, 
# for example, 
#    `height = 3E-4, width=3E-3` will show horizontal lines along `width`
#    `height = 3E-3, width=3E-4` will show vertical lines along `height`
#    `height = 3E-4, width=3E-4` will show nothing (which is your case)
```

[image]

To further illustrate the automated width and height of `geom_tile`, consider the following simple example:

```
# library(ggpubr)
# library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(
  x = c(2, 5, 7, 9),
  y = c(1, 2, 1,  2),
  z = factor(1:4)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  x = c(2, 5, 5.1, 9),
  y = c(1, 2, 1  ,  2),
  z = factor(1:4)
)

df3 <- data.frame(
  x = c(2, 5  , 7, 9),
  y = c(1, 1.1, 1, 2),
  z = factor(1:4)
)

df4 <- data.frame(
  x = c(2, 5  , 5.1, 9),
  y = c(1, 1.1, 1  , 2),
  z = factor(1:4)
)

ggarrange(
  ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)),
  ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)),
  ggplot(df3, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)),
  ggplot(df4, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)),
  labels = paste0("df", 1:4),
  ncol = 2, 
  nrow = 2
)
```

Therefore, it will be just simpler to use `geom_point` to visualize "raw GPS points".

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you for very detailed claficitation, however I need to plot it using `geom_tile`, which is not showing for me

Comment: That is why I posted the question, can you please look into my example below?

Comment: @Petr Sure, I have added some explanations to the "strange" behavior of `geom_tile`